# Citing with ACS style

Tags: citing, chemistry

Can anyone please help me to cite with ACS style because whatever the command I use it doesn't work, I always get either a question mark or just the name of the reference in bold

so please if anyone of you is using this style and can give me the exact commands I would really appreciate it

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number sounds like a possibe

Comment: The official style for the ACS is `achemso`, which should work just fine - we will need an example to help more

Comment: @JosephWright I have seen the question in the link you mentioned but didn't get what the answer is saying, I am actually new to latex and I am using overleaf, I have seen many citation commands but they do not work when I use ACS style

Comment: The `achemso` style works like others, but note that it is `natbib`-based so you shouldn't be loading the `cite` package

Comment: @JosephWright It works now! thanks a lot